# Trim() vs IndexOf()

Tags: java, string, parsing, optimization, text-parsing

I am parsing 100 of files which contains 1000 of lines in it.

I have to check whether line starts with some keywords.

i have 2 options not sure which to consider.

option 1:

```
    String[] keywordsArr = { "Everything", "Think", "Result", "What", "#Shop",  "#Cure" };
    for (int i = 0; i < linesOfCode.length; i++) {

        for (String keyWord : keywordsEndingAtEndOfLogicalLine) {

            if (linesOfCode[i].indexOf(keyWord) > -1) {

                if (linesOfCode[i].trim().startsWith(keyWord)) {

                    linesOfCode[i] = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

option 2:

```
String[] keywordsArr = { "Everything", "Think", "Result", "What", "#Shop",  "#Cure" };
    for (int i = 0; i < linesOfCode.length; i++) {

        for (String keyWord : keywordsArr) {

            if (linesOfCode[i].trim().startsWith(keyWord)) {

                    linesOfCode[i] = "";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

frequency of line starting with Keywords is 1 in 100.

Comment: The second approach seems more cleaner way of doing it.But if you wanna remove all words present in the keywords array you shouldn't be using break as will cause the inner loop to break even if one match is found

Answer (score 0):

There is little point scanning the entire string for a keyword just to avoid looking for the keyword at the beginning of the string. If the idea was to avoid an expensive `trim`, then it might be reasonable to use a cheaper technique to find the first token in the line.

Note that the `startsWith` comparison can produce false positives in the case that the line starts with a word whose prefix is a keyword. For example, if the keyword were `break`, a code line such as:

```
breakfast = "ham and eggs";
```

would be incorrectly eliminated.

You might want to investigate using `StringTokenizer` to extract the first word in the string, or even better, use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is something regexes are really good for. You code is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesOfCode.length; ++i) {
    linesOfCode[i] = linesOfCode.replaceAll(
        "^\\s+(Everything|Think|Result|what|#Shop,#Cure).*", "");
}
```

but you might require word boundary (`\\b`) after the keyword. For more speed, you should compile your regex like

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
    ^\\s+(Everything|Think|Result|what|#Shop,#Cure)\\b");

for (int i = 0; i < linesOfCode.length; ++i) {
    if (Pattern.matcher(linesOfCode[i]).matches()) {
        linesOfCode[i] = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using continue instead of break. Instead of stopping the loop, continue will tell the program to go one level up, thus continuing the loop for the next item.

Comment: Once you execute `linesOfCode[i] = ""` it hardly makes sense to try more keywords, so the `break` seems quite appropriate.